# Создание правильного сообщения формата iso8583 и отправка его с помощью java

Tags: java

Работаю с форматом iso8583. Нашел библиотеку https://github.com/imohsenb/ISO8583-Message-Client-java.

Но правильно не собирает.

Передать:

```
Message size 30

Message type 0800
P0007 Transmission Date and Time LEN=10 OFFS=20 '1113085120'
P0011 Systems Trace Audit Number LEN=6 OFFS=25 '851694'
P0070 Network Management Code LEN=3 OFFS=28 '001'
```

Нужно собрать подобное сообщение (формат iso8583) :

```
00 1e 30 38 30 30 82 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 11 13 12 53 20 12 34 56 03 01
```

Сейчас формируется неправильное сообщение подобное этому:

```
3038303082200800222000000000000000000011130851201234560301
```

Можете подсказать может другие библиотеки или как формировать подобные сообщения средствами java?
Вот исходный код как я пытаюсь отправлять:

```
public class newClient2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ISOException, ISOClientException, IOException {
        ISOMessage isoMessage = ISOMessageBuilder.Packer(VERSION.V1987)
                .networkManagement()
                .mti(MESSAGE_FUNCTION.Request, MESSAGE_ORIGIN.Acquirer)
                .processCode("000000")
                .setField(FIELDS.F7_TransmissionDataTime,  "1113085120")
                .setField(FIELDS.F11_STAN,  "1234560301")
                .setHeader("303830308220")
                .build();

        ISOClient client = ISOClientBuilder.createSocket("172.20.104.69", 5803)
                .build();
        System.out.println(isoMessage.toString());

        client.connect();
        String response = Arrays.toString(client.sendMessageSync(isoMessage)) ;
        System.out.println("response = " + response);
        client.disconnect();

    }
}
```

Хотелось бы конечно составлять сообщение из обычной кодировки. Но для начала хотелось бы, чтобы это заработало.
 Ошибку сейчас выдает:  Error message: TParser::GetMMDDHHMMSSFieldBCD: could not ParseMMDDHHMMSSbcd

Comment: Оба сообщения являются валидными ISO8583 сообщениями. Первый в формате HEX, второй в ASCII - у вас что-то с кодировками. Поиграйтесь в [онлайн парсером](https://neapay.com/online-tools/iso8583-message-parser.html)

Comment: Мне нужно с помощью java собрать подобное сообщение 00 1e 30 38 30 30 82 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 11 13 12 53 20 12 34 56 03 01 и послать его на сервер. Вот из этих 3 полей  Message size 30

Message type 0800
P0007 Transmission Date and Time LEN=10 OFFS=20 '06.07 8:58:39'
P0011 Systems Trace Audit Number LEN=6 OFFS=25 '82'
P0070 Network Management Code LEN=3 OFFS=28 '001'

Comment: По хорошему я хотел бы 10тичные данные и остальные обычные данные (время,буквы и тд) конвертировать в iso8583 и посылать их на сокет.